# Python ExcelWriter formatting 'all borders'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have this [image]

I want this

[image]

I look at the docs but I cannot see a function that would achieve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a format to columns with something like this (you will have to play with the styles to get the thickness you want):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

border_fmt = workbook.add_format({'bottom':5, 'top':5, 'left':5, 'right':5})
worksheet.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, len(df), len(df.columns)), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': border_fmt})
writer.save()
```

And here is a link to the format examples: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

Comment: The 'A:D' any way of making that more generic?

Comment: You can also set the column formats like this: worksheet.set_column(0, 3, 12, border_fmt), or in your case, maybe something like worksheet.set_column(0, len(df.columns) - 1, 12, border_fmt)

Comment: For some reason I get weird results all the columns have borders below where the numbers are, thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Try conditional formatting instead: worksheet.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, len(df), len(df.columns)), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': border_fmt}). I updated the answer to use this instead.